# ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cdd

Tags: java, android, emulation

I have a problem with emulator in android studio and I have no idea why. Can anyone help me? Here is a picture [image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Can you add some code to your question? It would also be nice to have the error message in your question directly.

Comment: Please include any relevant information in text form, rather than linking to an image. Also a bit more context would be helpful, ideally a minimal code example causing the problem.

Comment: ty guys for help but i reinstal all drivers and windows on my computger and now is working ty any way:D